# gmail removes all styles from <td> if it has a background gradient

Tags: css, gmail, html-email, email-client

I have discovered a strange issues with gmail where if my HTML email has any form of CSS3 gradient e.g:

```
<th style="text-align:right; font-size:14px; background:#ededed; background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ededed), to(#ebebeb)); background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ededed, #ebebeb); font-weight:bold;">
```

It will remove all styles from this `<th>`. As soon as I remove the background gradient stuff it works fine and leaves the rest of the styles in place. I have tried changing this to background: -moz-linear... all with the same effect. If gmail doesn't like it, it strips all styles from this element.

Has anybody else experienced this? Is there a solution to fix this?

I have tested the same email with Thunderbird and Mac Mail without any problems.

Comment: CSS support in virtually all email clients is not up to web standards. Often times this is intentional to prevent abuse from spammers. I've never heard of this before but I would guess that it is there on purpose for one reason or another. The only sure way to get that gradient in is an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gmail just does strange stuff with CSS in emails in general. Being that CSS support is so hit-or-miss, I'm not surprised that something as 'advanced' as a CSS3 gradient would be totally wrong.

The other thing that you have to consider is that *most* email clients won't recognize a CSS gradient, so I wouldn't bother trying.

If you want something to appear with a gradient, and you want it to show up for most email clients, you're going to have to create it as an image that is placed as content.

Answer (score 2):

It is not supported in CSS email.  A limited options are available.

Check this http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: css email support is back in the stone ages. you're not going to be able to do much except nest tables and hate life

Comment: If only thunderbird was in that list, it would tick nearly all of the boxes.

Answer (score 1):

If Gmail doesn't like any part of your style declaration on any given element, it strips out the entire declaration for that element. One workaround is to specify parts of your declaration as `!important`. That way Gmail only ignores the bits it doesn't like.

Comment: does not seem to be that straightforward... I tried it out to no success